# Cypress: case insensitive way of matching sub-string passed through variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

Trying to assert that my text contains the substring (case insensitive)

```
var valueInSearchbox;
 cy.view({ name: "FilterOnName" }).as('currentView');
 cy.get('@currentView').field({name:'FullName'}).find('input').invoke('val').then((resultText)=>{
    valueInSearchbox = resultText;
 })

cy.view({name:"list"}).as('currentView');
    cy.get('@currentView').field({name:'Patient'}).filter(":visible").find('input').each(($input)=>{
       cy.wrap($input).invoke('val').should($value => {
         expect($value).to.contain(valueInSearchbox);
       })
    })
```

The above works fine with case sensitive[i.e if the variable "valueInSearchbox" has "text1" and the list has "hello text1" ],
but if the variable "valueInSearchbox" has "text1" and the list has "hello TEXT1" then it fails.

How do i achieve case insensitive way of verifying the presence of substring?

Answer (score 2):

You could convert all strings to the same case.

```
expect($value.toLowerCase()).to.contain(valueInSearchbox.toLowerCase());
```